# Django filter ManyToMany filed in query

Tags: django, filter, many-to-many

I need to filter field with ManyToMany in queryset. There must stay only active **Products**

```
class Product(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    active = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=True)


class Package(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
```

I tried something like this.

```
packages = Package.objects.all()
for package in packages:
    active_products = package.products.filter(active=True)
    package.products = active_products
```

but it updates my packages in database, when i need only change queryset.

expectation concept (do not really need nested structure, query set is fine):

```
 packages = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'First package', 'products': [
        {'id': 1, 'name': 'first product', 'active': True},
        {'id': 2, 'name': 'second product', 'active': True},
    ]},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'Second package', 'products': [
        {'id': 2, 'name': 'first product', 'active': True},
        {'id': 3, 'name': 'third product', 'active': True},
    ]},
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'Third package', 'products': []}

]
```

I thought about creating a list of dictionaries from  Packages by **.values()**, then iterate it and exclude all not active products.
Do you know any more elegant way to do it?

Comment: Are you using Django REST Framework?

Comment: @JPG, yes, but I wold like to make it in regular django  without serialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work. But I think that we can play using the `serializers.MethodSerialier`. If it fails probably we can try to return another thing instead of the `Productserializer` directly.

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'name')


class PackageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = serializers.MethodSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Package
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'products')

    def get_products(self, obj):
        products = obj.products.filter(active=True)
        return ProductSerializer(products, many=True)


packages = Package.objects.filter(products__active=True)
serializer = PackageSerializer(packages, many=True)
# do something with the serializer
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you won't get a ***nested output*** from Django :( But you will get something *similar* with ***`.values()`*** method of **QuerySet** class as,

```
results = Package.objects.filter(products__active=True).values('id', 'name', 'products__id', 'products__name', 'products__active')
filtered_result = [result for result in results if result['products__active']]
```

Comment: This code filters and show packages with all active products. While I need to show only active products in packages (show packages any way). Do not really need nested structure just showing concept of expectations.

Comment: @KuskoAndrew Updated my answer :)

Comment: updated code doing same. It filters Package while I need filter products. Show packages any way. But products in package must be active. How to filter ManyToMany field for every model?

Comment: `filtered_result` will hold the required result